# Protect Sheet but unprotect text input shape

Tags: excel, vba

I have been Googling and searching this site. I am sorry if this is a simple question or has been answered often, but I have yet to find my solution.

In essence, I have created a sheet that is filled with input form control objects (not ActiveX) stuff and a few shapes.

So I have this sheet I want to protect, but I want to select specific shapes (a couple text boxes) that allow input. I don't want the user moving stuff, clicking random cells, etc. I want 5-6 specific form controls I have named to allow input, and everything else is locked down.

How do I do this? Again, sorry for what should be a simple answer, but apparently my searching isn't asking the correct question.

```
' Locks the main config pages and hides everything the user shouldn't touch
Public Sub ProtectUserFromUser()

    Set configsheet = Sheets(MgmtConfigSheet)
    Set authsheet = Sheets(AuthDataSheet)
    Set mydebugsheet = Sheets(debugsheet)

    authsheet.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    configsheet.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    mydebugsheet.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden

    Call UnprotectInput
    configsheet.Protect

End Sub

' All the fields user should be able to input on here
Private Sub UnprotectInput()
    Set x = configsheet.Shapes("testInputBox")
    x.Locked = False

End Sub
```

What's happening here is I can still click around and select cells, but I cannot type any input characters in the `testInputBox`. The variables when I set the `Sheets` are good. How can I make the `configsheet` only respond or accept input in select locations/shapes/ranges, etc?

**UPDATE** To make it clear, the text box I am trying to type in while not allowing user movement of the text box, was created as a `Shape` and it's embedded within a worksheet, not in a form. The `Locked` and `Lock text` boxes are unchecked in the `Shape` property.

Comment: I think you need to add some parameters to `configsheet.Protect` line. `Protect method` allows to set what and in which way should be protected. I think [THIS LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff840611%28v=office.14%29.aspx) will be a good point to start. Alternatively, try to macro-record protection to get correct syntax.

Comment: Right click on the form control and click on Format Control and the set the locked property to chrcked/unchecked under the Protection Tab

Comment: I right clicked on the specific form control input text box I am testing with. The `protected` field under `properties` is unchecked. Yet I can click around and select fields on the spreadsheet, but I cannot type values in the form control.

Comment: @KazJaw I am reading your link, and I changed my method call to `configsheet.Protect (DrawingObjects = False)` but it changed nothing.

Comment: One moment posting an answer

Comment: Sorry. I had to delete my answer... @KazJaw has already covered that in the link mentioned in the first comment.

Comment: `you will have to Check the Locked property. Similarly to allow typing, you will have to uncheck the locked property.` How do you do this via VBA? Also, you mention setting `DrawingObjects` to `False`. I have tried that (mentioned in comments in top level question). That changed nothing. However, I don't plan on ever having a password as this will be a public WB.

Comment: Oh shoot @SiddharthRout. I mentioned in my comment back, it wasn't working `(re: DrawingObjects = False)`. It's allowing everything but edit of that field. If 2 people say the same thing, perhaps it requires rest...

Comment: I already tested it and it works but since that suggestion was given by @KazJaw first, I would wait till he posts a comment/answer :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout, it's ok if you post the full answer here. You made much more effort than me to help Nathan and any reward for that should be granted to you in this situation.

Comment: @Nathan: Since it is not working for you then may I see the workbook? If yes, then you can upload it in any free filesharing site like www.wikisend.com and share the link here? If the workbook has sensitive information then you could create a sample workbook as well... :)

Comment: OK after playing around a little more (and sleep), I realized that the text field is actually a shape, and not a form control. Which makes sense, duh! So I am going to look for making a shape editable (but not movable) while leaving everything else on the page protected. Unless someone knows the answer off hand? I am going to reword and edit my original question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do 2 things. Neither require VBA.

1. You need to make sure the form control is unlocked
2. Make sure the cell that the form control is writing to is unprotected. (format cells dialogue and unprotect cell)

---

**EDIT: Below is updated to reflect working on shape, not form control**

1. Make sure the shape is unprotected (you are doing this in your existing code)
2. Your spreadsheet protect code needs to also change to allow editing of objects

Change this line

```
configsheet.Protect
```

to this:

```
configsheet.Protect _
    DrawingObjects:=False, _
    Contents:=True, _
    Scenarios:=True
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I updated the question. It's a text box `Shape`, not a form control. It's embedded directly in a worksheet.